# Can NATS keep messages in memory if no workers are online at the moment (producer-consumers pattern)?

Tags: python, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I would like to use NATS to distribute tasks among several worker-processes. Everything works as expected if I have at least one worker "online", but if there are no worker-processes, messages are just thrown away, when I turn on one worker I got no messages (which were created when it was not online).

I know how to do it with RabbitMQ, but is it possible to do it with NATS?

I do project in Python, producer-process in aiohttp, worker-processes are also in Python and do some CPU-heavy tasks.

Comment: Try verbose mode true see if anything useful pops up

Comment: @Orenico Unfortunately the only thing I see from the logs is that NATS received the message: ```[1] 2021/09/26 15:24:30.024514 [TRC] 10.10.0.1:45370 - cid:14 - "v0.11.4:python3" - <<- MSG_PAYLOAD: ["Hello-19"]
[1] 2021/09/26 15:24:30.538533 [TRC] 10.10.0.1:45370 - cid:14 - "v0.11.4:python3" - <<- [PUB updates  8]
[1] 2021/09/26 15:24:30.538557 [TRC] 10.10.0.1:45370 - cid:14 - "v0.11.4:python3" - <<- MSG_PAYLOAD: ["Hello-20"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this day official Python connector does not support NATS/Jetsream [issue-209](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py/issues/209)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with JetStream? JetStream retains messages so they can be replayed. You can configure your stream to only discard the message once it's been acknowledged.
Not sure what the state of python client is in regard to JetStream, I know it it being worked on. https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py

Comment: No I am not familiar with NATS, I just decided to play around and find what can I use instead of RabbitMQ as more lightweight alternative. I found that Jetstream have functionality which looks like my case, ran container with `-js` (jetsream) flag, but message do not persist. I also can't find any example for my use case, though persistent  message in RabbitMQ is very easy to setup. But have no idea how to do it with NATS. Could you share more details?

Comment: You can start by looking at the JetStream documentation: https://docs.nats.io/jetstream/jetstream

Comment: You can also administer and even play with streams using the 'natscli' tool (https://github.com/nats-io/natscli) besides using the JS calls in your nats client library.

Very simple example first use `nats bench test --js --pub 1` (this will publish some messages in to a stream) then after that you can get a 'replay' of all the messages in the stream using `nats bench test --js --sub 1`

Comment: @JNM I guess that I do not create cluster properly, on the other hand I do not get any errors when do `docker run --network host -p 4222:4222 nats -js --name test_server --cluster_name test_cluster`. But my client app can't connect to test_cluster.